# Why are some pseudopotentials not readable in Quantum Espresso?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, pseudopotentials

I am using the pseudopotentials generated using "atomic" code by `A. Dal Corso` after downloading the `pslibrary.0.3.1`. Some of the pseudopotentials generated are working properly but some are not giving the error that `pseudopotential.UPF` is not readable in Quantum Espresso. The properly working and not readable pseudopotentials along with the scf.in file are provided in a github repository in [SCF folder](https://github.com/EPR-copenhagen/SCF.git). Any suggestion regarding this issue would be of a great help.

Comment: +1 but please provide your files according to the rules [described here](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5).

Comment: It would help if you stated what program you are working with.

Comment: @SusiLehtola looking at the github repository linked within the post, it is clear that this is for Quantum ESPRESSO. I added the QE tag for clarity.

Comment: Yes the software is Quantum Espresso. sorry for incovenience.

Comment: Why don't you add the files to the GitHub repository that we have been using for all the other posts on this site? This is the first time I have seen someone add files to a different GitHub repository, and all other files that were added to a GitHub repository were added to the ***same*** GitHub repository.